# Django test not created testing database and not work

Tags: django, testing, installation, testcase

everyone

I created TestCase, but when I put the command "python manage.py test", this test don't work.
Can you help me, please?

```
from django.test import TestCase
from accounts.models import UserProfile 



class AccountsTestCase(TestCase):    
    def setUp(self):
        print('test_setUp')
        UserProfile.objects.create(email='test@test.com', password='user111333')

    def get_user(self):    
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(email='test@test.com')
```

Comment: did you configured test database in settings.py

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `assert` methods and the `test_` acronym at the begin of the function. Without them you cannot test.

I think this approach will do the trick:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from accounts.models import UserProfile 

class AccountsTestCase(TestCase):    
    def setUp(self):
        print('test_setUp')
        self.someuser =UserProfile.objects.create(email='test@test.com',password='user111333')

    def test_get_user(self):    
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(email='test@test.com', password='abcd123')
        user.save()
        self.assertTrue(user)
        self.assertEqual(user.email,'test@test.com')
        self.assertNotEqual(user, self.someuser)
        self.assertNotEqual(user.email,'test@other_test.com')
```

Here is a list with more assertions:

```
Assertions
```

| Method | Checks that |
| --- | --- |
| assertEqual(a, b) | a == b |
| assertNotEqual(a, b) | a != b |
| assertTrue(x) | bool(x) is True |
| assertFalse(x) | bool(x) is False |
| assertIs(a, b) | a is b |
| assertIsNot(a, b) | a is not b |
| assertIsNone(x) | x is None |
| assertIsNotNone(x) | x is not None |
| assertIn(a, b) | a in b |
| assertNotIn(a, b) | a not in b |
| assertIsInstance(a, b) | isinstance(a, b) |